# Input stream picture is received but blank on Android

Tags: android, image, bluetooth, save

I am trying to send an image via Bluetooth. After successfully connecting devices, picking and sending files it seems all right. But the phone receiving the file shows the name of the file but when opened the file seems to be empty.

```
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");

        File pictureFile = getDir();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mmInStream);

        try {       

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

             mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_FILE, -1,
             -1, pictureFile.getAbsolutePath().getBytes())
             .sendToTarget();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    private File getDir() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),
                "Test");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        Log.d("Gauss", "Saving to: " + mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Any help, please?

Comment: It may help you http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices

Comment: I read the documentation, the problem is more specific. I got the image transferred, but it is an empty file?